# How do I set up a server to monitor devices like Ubuntu distro laptops? What tools?

Tags: networking, server, laptop, monitoring, tools

I have a number of devices to experiment on, over 20. I would like to have tools that are freely available. I was hoping the community could help me through this process. I want to resurrect the equipment I have on hand. So far, I've installed popOS on two laptops that previously ran Windows 10 that I am testing, as well as one desktop that will serve as a server. My plan is to have a way to monitor and deploy any changes I make to it. I'd like to be able to restrict and monitor these devices without having the end-users to create a password and username if it is possible.

This is my first time setting up a server, so I don't know much about it. So far, I've installed Ubuntu server on a USB as a .bin, booted it on a desktop, and installed it without any add-ons.

Comment: What do you want to monitor from this devices?

Comment: Start by having your Ubuntu server (which supported Ubuntu release?) be the DHCP server for the PopOS nodes. PopOS is not supported on AskUbuntu. For debugging, install Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: I'd like to keep an eye on the laptops' activity for monitoring purposes, particularly the websites they visit and block them. Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS manual installation is the version I'm using.